# Why tag value can't be compared with a same string?

Tags: html, python-3.x, lxml

```
import lxml.html
strings = """<p> <!--startprint-->xyz <br>　
xyz <br>　xyz  </p>"""
root=lxml.html.document_fromstring(strings)
for e in root.iter() :
    print(e.tag)
```

To print all elements tag value.

```
html
body
p
<cyfunction Comment at 0x7f6819bb11b8>
br
br
```

The comment in html string here is `<!--startprint-->`,the tag value of it is `<cyfunction Comment at 0x7f6819bb11b8>`,i want to compare `<!--startprint-->`'s tag value with `<cyfunction Comment at 0x7f6819bb11b8>`.

```
import lxml.html
strings = """<p> <!--startprint-->xyz <br>　
xyz <br>　xyz  </p>"""
root=lxml.html.document_fromstring(strings)
for e in root.iter() :
    print(e.tag)
    print(e.tag ==  "<cyfunction Comment at 0x7f6819bb11b8>")
```

The result is aas below:

```
html
False
body
False
p
False
<cyfunction Comment at 0x7f6819bb11b8>
False
br
False
br
False
```

Why is not as below:

```
html
False
body
False
p
False
<cyfunction Comment at 0x7f6819bb11b8>
True
br
False
br
False
```

For `<!--startprint-->`, the tag value is `<cyfunction Comment at 0x7f6819bb11b8>`,why `<cyfunction Comment at 0x7f6819bb11b8>` != `<cyfunction Comment at 0x7f6819bb11b8>`?
What a joke?

Comment: `0x7f6819bb11b8` is a memory address. It changes every time you run the program. What is the problem that you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this will satisfy your requirements but you can get the function name and then compare that is it a function `Comment`
Below is an example of how to do it.

```
>>> for e in root.iter() :
...     try:
...         e.tag.__name__
...     except:
...         pass
... 
>>> 'Comment'
```

You can match strings as if its a function and it is a function named commnet.

I don't think function objects can be compared in this way although you can compare them using their attributes but can't compare a whole object with other